# Combining different overflow properties

Tags: css, overflow

I'm trying to create a multi-threaded navigation similar to OS X's column view:

[image: Starting point: nice columns with arrows]

In the markup here, I've got a list of lists sitting in a parent `<nav>` with a defined height. Then each `li` is floated left with a defined width and a `height: 100%`. Then I do the [css triangle trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) to make the little arrow, and position it hanging out into the next column with a positive `z-index`. So far, so good.

Column 2, however, is too long: I want it to scroll. When I assign that `ul` an `overflow-y: auto`, however, I get:

[image: Scrollbars! Scrollbars EVERYWHERE!]

Wait a minute! Where'd all those scrollbars come from!? I didn't want scrollbars for x! But even when I set `overflow-x: visible`, it ignores it and gives me a scrollbar. This is, sadly, [as specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapse-scroll). Is there a CSS workaround for this? Do I have to write some cranky JavaScript to react to the lists scrolling and reposition the arrows?

EDIT: added [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agugeq/3)

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ demo showing what you have so far? I can guess what the problem is, but it's really much easier with a test case.

Comment: Sure: http://jsbin.com/agugeq/3